# How to install newer supertux2 from sources

Tags: software-installation, games, 19.10, source-code

I wanted to test my laptop's and pc's graphics cards by playing supertux2. It turned out that Lenovo G550 GL40 graphical chipset works better then Nvidia G220 on PC. Graphics on Nvidia GT220 with proprietary drivers installed works with short time lags happening every 20-30 seconds even if processor almost idle.

I tested supertux2 v0.6.0 and passed all available game maps, so *To be continued...* message appeared. It was interesting to watch maps that should be further. So I decided to install the current development version of supertux2. The question is how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Installation instructions from github](https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux/blob/master/INSTALL.md) clearly explains what packages or libraries are required before installation in **REQUIREMENTS** section.

I've installed it the next way on both Ubuntu 19.10 host and 18.04 VirtualBox VM:

- `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libglew-dev \
      libalut-dev libopenal-dev libvorbis-dev libphysfs-dev libfribidi-dev \
      libcurl4-openssl-dev libfreetype6-dev libraqm-dev doxygen`
- `git clone https://github.com/SuperTux/supertux.git`
- `cd supertux`
- `git submodule update --init --recursive`
- `rm -fr build` (This step is optional. I tried `./configure`, so it created a `build` directory)
- `mkdir build && cd build`
- `cmake ..`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`